# JQuery Ajax requesting Web Method with both return and output value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have this strange situation where I have a `WebMethod` in WebService which needs to return a generic list and also need to have output Parameter attached to it.

And `$.ajax({ })` need to call this webservice and get both return value and outparameter in `.success()`.

Web Service is as below:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List < Category > GetAllCategory(out int TotalCountRecord) 
{
     List < Category > AllValues = new List < Category > ();
     //Some ADO.NET Code to Call Stored Procedure with output Value;
     SqlParameter OutParameter = new SqlParameter("@RecordCount", SqlDbType.Int);
     OutParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     TotalCountRecord = (int)(OutParameter.Value);
     //Pls. Don't Mind these sequence of the code.
     return AllValues;
}
```

Now is there a Possible way for me to call these code for JQuery Ajax Like

```
var a = 0;
$.ajax({
   url: 'WebService1.asmx/GetAllCategory',
   method: 'post',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: JSON.stringify({TotalCountRecord: a}),
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   success: function(data) {

    //Add data to Table
   //Show RecordCount at Footer of the Table
  }
```

Is these a way to address this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think its not possible.

you can return out parameter:

```
[WebMethod]
public static dynamic GetAllCategory(out int TotalCountRecord) 
{
 List < Category > AllValues = new List < Category > ();
 //Some ADO.NET Code to Call Stored Procedure with output Value;
 SqlParameter OutParameter = new SqlParameter("@RecordCount",SqlDbType.Int);
 OutParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 TotalCountRecord = (int)(OutParameter.Value);
 //Pls. Don't Mind these sequence of the code.
 return new{AllValues,TotalCountRecord};
}
```

now in ajax:

```
success: function(data) {
    Add data.AllValues to Table
    Show data.TotalCountRecord at Footer of the Table
}
```

Comment: ..I made some silly mistake at my end but your suggestion worked!!!! Thank you so much.....